# connect strings with condition in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say, I got a points index like that:

**sheet1**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
```

And a connection data, represents the relation between these points, like, the first 2 rows mean that `point_1` are connected with `point_75` and `point_78` :

**sheet2**

```
1   75
1   78
2   44
3   45
3   65
4   39
4   63
5   49
5   50
6   59
...
```

And I wish I could use some expression to represent that in `sheet1` like:

```
1   75,78
2   44
3   45,65
...
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is the maximum number of other points that a point is connected to?

Comment: @Bandersnatch there's 582 points... so I don't know how to count the max connection... According to my raw observation, the max number of points one point could connect is about 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function Konnect(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As String
    Dim ary, i As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    ary = r2
    v = r1.Value
    Konnect = ""

    For i = LBound(ary, 1) To UBound(ary, 1)
        If ary(i, 1) = v Then Konnect = Konnect & "," & ary(i, 2)
    Next i

    If Len(Konnect) <> 0 Then Konnect = Mid(Konnect, 2)
End Function
```

Then in *Sheet1* cell **B1** enter:

```
=Konnect(A1,Sheet2!A$1:B$10)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Naturally, you would change the ***10*** to match the actual table size on *Sheet2*.

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=Konnect(A1,Sheet2!A$1:B$10)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Could you please tell me where can I access `User Defined Function` please...

Comment: @AmarthGûl See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @AmarthGûl  You are quite welcome!

Comment: Nice!  I'll remember this. And "Bound(ary" too.  :-D